# how to debug thingsboard UI

Tags: thingsboard, vs-community-edition

I am trying to add new features in things board,is there a way to debug UI of things board community edition.

Can anyone suggest plugin/IDE/method to implement debug on Things board UI

Comment: use `console.log(x)` and view the output in the developer window (F12) > Console

Comment: @JacksonB's comment should be a correct answer, not a comment